# Approximating Functions Limit Integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $f, g \in L^1[0,1)$ such that $fg\in L^1[0,1)$. Can we find sequences $\{f_k\}\subseteq L^2[0,1)$ and $\{g_k\} \subseteq L^2[0,1)$ such that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_k(x)g_k(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx?
$$
I've tried playing around by choosing $f_k$ and $g_k$ such that
$$
\|f_k-f\|_{L^1} \to 0 \quad \& \quad \|g_k-g\|_{L^1} \to 0
$$
as $L^2$ is dense in $L^1$ and trying to find a suitable triangle inequality trick, but alas I haven't been successful. Any advice would be appreciate or a counterexample would be nice too.

Comment: How about truncating $f$ and $g$?

Comment: What do you mean? $f$ and $g$ are fixed functions in $L^1$.

Comment: I suppose you also require that $f_k\to f$ and $g_k\to g$ in some way? Otherwise just take $f_k(x)\equiv 1$ and $g_k\to fg$ in $L^1$ by the density of $L^2$ in $L^1$

Comment: I mean, you may set $$f_k(x) = f(x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|\leq k\}}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&|f(x)|\leq k,\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and likewise for $g_k$. Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that $f_k g_k\to fg$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Yes, I would like for $f_k$ and $g_k$ to be $L^2$. However, we only know that $f,g$ are in $L^1$.

Comment: The resulting $f_k$ and $g_k$ are not only in $L^2$, but also bounded!

Comment: I see. So you want to approximate by bounded functions. Does this then allow for the desired result?

Comment: Maybe apply DCT to interchange integration and limit?

Comment: @SangchulLee why not write this as an answer?

Comment: That's correct :) Note that $f_k g_k \to fg$ a.e. and $|f_k g_k|\leq |fg|$. So DCT is applicable.

Comment: @Lorago, I'm typing with my phone now on bed, and somehow it is extremely painful to write anything in the answer textbox now... I'll write an answer when I'm on my desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the truncated functions

$$ f_k(x) = f(x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|\leq k\}}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&|f(x)|\leq k,\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

and likewise $g_k(x) = g(x)\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{|g|\leq k\}}(x)$. Since each of $f_k$'s and $g_k$'s is bounded, it is in $L^2[0,1)$. Moreover, it is clear that

- $f_k \to f$ and $g_k \to g$ almost everywhere, and
- $|f_k g_k| \leq |fg|$.

So by the dominated convergence theorem, $\int f_k g_k \to \int f g$.